# Как проверить получен ли правильный html с помощью selenium python

Tags: html, python, selenium, web-scraping

У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором храниться список URL адресов, html которых мне нужно получить. Проблема состоит в том, что неизвестно был ли получен доступ к странице и собственно верный ли html. Есть какой то способ как узнать есть ли доступ к странице?

Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver


op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
with open('urls.txt') as file:
    for url in file:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
browser.close()
```

Comment: Если у пользователя нет доступа к контенту, то можно посмотреть по коду ответа сервера. 403 ошибка - нет доступа к содержимому

Comment: Обычно, сервер возвращает код `200` в случае успеха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под "правильным" понимать ответ [200 (ОК)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP), то можно проверить ответный код модулем `requests`:

```
import requests
try: 
    response = requests.head(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # do your stuff
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("url not ok")
```

Впрочем, в этот код легко можно добавить и любые другие коды.